# Transfer Azure subscription - MSDN to MSDN

Tags: azure

I need to switch all my ressources from one subscription to another, basically as described here

https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Microsoft-Azure-Tutorials/Transfer-an-Azure-subscription

but in my case both subscription are MSDN subscriptions and the transfer option is not visible. Can this be done somehow without contacting Microsoft?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-subscription-transfer#transferring-visual-studio-mpn-and-pay-as-you-go-devtest-subscriptions)?

Comment: The link is helpful - it contains a lot of information that I have partially seen on channel 9 before. Sadly, it does not explain how to transfer resources from one "Visual Studio Professional" subscription to another (newer) subscription with the same name (but different id):

Comment: well, to transfer resources you use the move function

Comment: I think that is the answer - transfer is only possible on a "per resource" basis. You could make this an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

transfer is only possible on a "per resource" basis. [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources) covers moving resources.